# OpenID Connect vs OAuth 2.0

Tags: spring-boot, docker, keycloak

What is the difference between OpenID Connect and Oauth 2.0?
which one is recommended to use when the application is running in docker containers?
Can someone explain briefly with an example?

I have used openid connect . Not able to deploy in docker .
I am not saying because of openid but I want to know the things

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

**OAuth 2.0:**

OAuth 2.0 is an authorization framework that allows third-party applications to obtain limited access to a user's resources, typically on a different service, without exposing the user's credentials.
It is widely used for delegated authorization, such as allowing a third-party application to access resources on behalf of a user (e.g., accessing a web site from a third-party application).

**OpenID Connect (OIDC):**

OpenID Connect is an authentication layer built on top of OAuth 2.0, providing identity verification and single sign-on (SSO) capabilities.
It is used for user authentication, allowing users to log in to multiple applications using a single set of credentials (SSO).

**Recommendation for Docker:**

Both OAuth 2.0 and OpenID Connect can be used in Docker containers, as they are standard protocols that can be implemented in any environment. The choice between OAuth 2.0 and OIDC depends on your application's specific requirements:

- If your application needs only authorization (granting access to resources), OAuth 2.0 may be sufficient.
- If your application requires user authentication (verifying the identity of users), OIDC is recommended as it extends OAuth 2.0 with authentication capabilities.

**Example:**

Suppose you have a web application running in Docker containers that allow users to access their web site through any IDP (example: Google)

OAuth 2.0: Your application can use OAuth 2.0 to obtain an access token from IDP authorization server. The access token allows your application to access the web site on behalf of the user.

OpenID Connect: If your application also requires user authentication (e.g., logging in with Google), you can use OpenID Connect. After the user logs in with their IDP credentials, your application receives an ID Token containing information about the user, such as their name and email address.